# How to solve $x'=A(t)x+b(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve $x'=A(t)x+b(t)$ where $$A(t)=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 2t & 0 \\ 1 & t \end{array}\right) $$ and $$b(t)=\left(\begin{array}{c} e^{t^2}  \\ -4e^{t^2} \end{array}\right)  $$ I tried puting $$x = (y ,z)^t $$ we get the system $$y' = 2ty+2tz+e^{t^2} \\ z'=y+tz-4e^{t^2}$$ but I don't think that can do something with this, I mean if  I do $$y'=2t(z'-tz+4e^{t^2})+2tz+e^{t^2}$$ does not seems to help any idea?

Comment: The matrix is lower triangular: the first line is $y'=2ty+e^{t^2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first differential equation is easy to integrate:
$$y'=2ty+e^{t^2}$$
$$y'e^{-t^2}-2te^{-t^2}y=1$$
$$(ye^{-t^2})'=1$$
Integrate both sides. Then solve the second DE:
$$z'=y+tz-4e^{t^2}$$